# Concrete bound of expected value of a difference of I.I.D. Uniform Random Variables

Tags: expected-value, nonparametric, probability-inequalities

In the following, $X,X_1,X_2,\dots X_n$ are I.I.D. uniform random variables in $[0,1]^d$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The problem I am attempting to solve is Exercise 2.4 from Gyorfi's "A distribution free approach to non-parametric regression", where the objective is to prove

$$
\mathbb{E}\{\text{min}_{i=1,..,n}||X-X_{i}||\}\geq\frac{d}{d+1}\big(\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}+1)^{\frac{1}{d}}/\sqrt{\pi})\cdot n^{-\frac{1}{d}}
$$
In an attempt to prove this, I have proven that
$$\mathbb{P}\{\text{min}_{i=1,...,n}\leq t\}\leq n\cdot \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}+1)}\cdot t^d$$
but am stuck on how to get from here to the inequality for the expectation. I have tried using Markov's inequality, but can't seem to make it work.  One idea I have pursued is that
$$\mathbb{P}\{\text{min}_{i=1,...,n}||X-X_{i}||\leq \big(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2}+1)^{1/d}}{n^{1/d}\cdot\sqrt{\pi}}\big)\}=1$$
But, again, I am unable to connect this to the inequality asserted for the expectation. Any help would be appreciated.